# apply active class to static li tag in angluarjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have static ul li list as below.

```
<li ng-click="revenueTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.revenue}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-click="ecpmTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.ecpm}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-click="fillRateTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.fillrate}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-click="impressionTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.impression}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-click="cvvsTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.cvv}}
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to apply active class on clicking on particular li and it should also remove all active class applied to other li.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set active tab identifier in scope and compare in ng-class to assign `active` class. check this jsbin link [here](http://jsbin.com/vukukuxoce/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, Here is one of many AngularJS ways to do it

```
<li ng-class="active: aclass == 'rev' " ng-click="aclass = 'rev'; revenueTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.revenue}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="active: aclass == 'ecpm' " ng-click="aclass = 'ecpm'; ecpmTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.ecpm}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="active: aclass == 'fill' " ng-click="aclass = 'fill'; fillRateTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.fillrate}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="active: aclass == 'imp' " ng-click="aclass = 'imp'; impressionTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.impression}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="active: aclass == 'cvv' " ng-click="aclass = 'cvv'; cvvsTab()">
  <a class="btnIntoTab">
    <span class="tabValue">{{aggregation.cvv}}
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: It's not applying active class.